# How to ignore whitespaces and new line feeds while parsing a XML file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, whitespace, removing-whitespace

how can I ignore whitespaces while parsing a XML file. It always calls the `characters(...)` method again, while after the end element a `'\n'` or `'\r'` is following, so it calls this method twice, instead of only once.

Comment: Most of the `XML` parsers handle this on their own. BTW which parser you are using ?

Comment: I use this parser: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser. I know that there is a function called ignorableWhitespaces(...) but I don't know how to use this function and i don't know what it exactly does.

Answer (score 1):

A SAXParser that is parsing a document against a DTD calls `ignorableWhitespace()` when it encounters whitespace in *element content*. For example, if this XML fragment

```
<ol>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
</ol>
```

is parsed against this DTD fragment:

```
<!ELEMENT ol (li+)>
<!ELEMENT li (#PCDATA)>
```

the SAXParser would call `characters(...)` for `"one"` and `"two"`, and `ignorableWhitespace(...)` for all the white space between the elements.

Note also that this applies only to parsing against a DTD. When using a Schema, `ignorableWhitespace(...)` is not called (even though the same kind of information is available).

Comment: Okay, thank you but this didn't solve my problem. Between my elements in the given XML file are whitespaces e.g. 
<element>..
....<test/>
</element>

(marked with the dots) and always characters() is called in this case. Solved it with a simple return: 
    if (content.length() == 0)
      return; // ignore whitespaces